# Find out if there is way for coin change solution given infinite number of coins of value <= 10^9 and amount <=10^9

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

How to find out if coin change exists for large sum (`<=10^9`) and infinite number of large coin values (`<=10^9`) .

So question is to output `1` if a change exists or `0` otherwise.

e.g.  given two coins of value (`c1=1000000000`and `c2=99999999`) and amount to be changed `A = 99999999` gives `1` because a change exists (with coin `c2`).

My solution for small amount:

- `S[]` is an array of coin denominations.
- `m` is the total amount that we need to make by summing the coin values (there is an unlimited supply of each coin),
- and `n` is the number of coins that need to be in the solution.

I wrote this, but it gets so slow when coin number gets big...

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 // S is given coin array , m = amount , n = total numbers 
int thereExists( int S[], int m, int n )
{
    int i, j, x, y;

// We need n+1 rows as the table is consturcted in bottom up manner using 
// the base case 0 value case (n = 0)
int table[n+1][m];

// Fill the enteries for 0 value case (n = 0)
for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    table[0][i] = 1;

// Fill rest of the table enteries in bottom up manner  
for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        // Count of solutions including S[j]
        x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;

        // Count of solutions excluding S[j]
        y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;

        // total count
        table[i][j] = x + y;
    }
}
return table[n][m-1]>0?1:0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the specific question?

Comment: @JulienBernu i don't get ,i think question is self contained , I have modified the question

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution with large values? Is it too slow? Does it crash? Does it give a wrong answer? ...

Comment: @JulienBernu it will be slow , but as of now it crashes for large values

Comment: what is the constrain on number of coins?

Comment: I edited your post to make it clearer. You are trying to find optimization, is that it?

Comment: @Yerken contraint on number of coins is max 5000

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ishtupeed/HackerRank/blob/master/Project-Euler/Coin%20partitions.cpp) I used the concept of [Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler078) problem. IDK if it'd work for such huge dataset. But you can take a look at the concept.